# Send UDP packets from devmachine to AVD Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, udp

How can I send UDP packets to the AVD emulator?
I tried to send on 10.0.2.15 (Which is the device's local IP) but that does not work. The device can reach the webserver (Either on 10.0.2.2 or its real IP) on the devmachine but the devmachine can't send UDP packets to the device.

How can I fix this?

edit: I have defined `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UDP does not work on the Android Simulator. Use a real phone/tablet to test UDP.

Comment: Not true, UDP works, but the AVD device is behind a virtual firewall.